# Blackberry OS 5 web application performance tuning

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, browserfield, blackberry-os5

We have a web application in jquerymobile 1.0.1 and jquery 1.7.1. For BB devices we have created a wrapper application using BrowserField JDE 5 API, which is used to launch the application UI. Using web DOM cache to work in offline mode.

Performance wise the application works good on OS6+ devices, but on OS5+ device it is a real pain. Browsing application is too slow.

We have 3 out of 6 pages due to there dynamic nature; they are scripted in jquery.

Please suggest few good performance tuning steps that would help in improving the application performance.